# Change Modal Heading to h1 using Carbon Components React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carbon-design-system, carbon-components

I'm using the Carbon Components React Modal. One of the controls is modalHeading. This works great but defaults to `<h3>` tag.

Semantically, I would like to use `<h1>` tags instead. Does anyone know how I would change this?

```html
<Modal open passiveModal modalHeading="Let's Continue Your Online Set Up"></Modal>
```

Renders this heading:

```html
<h3 id="cds--modal-header__heading--modal-7" class="cds--modal-header__heading">Let's Continue Your Online Set Up</h3>
```

I'm new to React so if there isn't a Carbon way of changing the h3 tag, how would I do this in React?

Comment: From the docs, it seems like there is a way with `ComposedModal`. You need to try that out.

Comment: @CodeThing I looked through those docs and didn't see anything other than that you use modalHeading to add copy. If you read something that would help me change the default h3 to an h1, I would love to hear it.

Comment: What version you are using.

Comment: The latest version.